# Several app on a single domain?

Tags: facebook

I want host several app on a single domain.

Apps url will be https://www.domain.com/app1/, https://www.domain.com/app2/ etc...

Can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Absolutely, there's no reason you can't do this.